# Prevent a returning function from execution if a condition on parameters is true

Tags: c++

like said on the title, I was wondering if it was possible to stop a function from execution. In my particular case, I'm trying to make an operator[] and prevent utilisator from using it if the value gave in parameters is too high :

in .h:

```
class Vec4
{
    float x,y,z,w;

    public:

        float operator[](const unsigned int i);
}
```

in .cpp :

```
float Vec4::operator[](const unsigned int i)
{
    if(i == 0) return x;
    if(i == 1) return y;
    if(i == 2) return z;
    if(i == 3) return w;
}
```

I'd like to "break" the function if i >=4 
For the moment I'm just making a console output and return 0.0f

thank you to show me if there is a way ... or not !

Comment: So what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*stop*" or "*break*" a function?

Comment: How about using Exception for that?

Comment: You're looking for [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert).

Comment: I guess he wants to check if `i` is within range.

Comment: As a side note, it may be much easier to implement your class if you declare `float x, y, z, w` as an array `float data[4]` this would reduce the code for your operator to `/*Do range check first*/ return data[i]`

Comment: If you know `i` at compile-time, make it a template parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do at least 4 things.

1. Return a known error value from the function. For eg. `-1` if the input value is no good.
2. Raise an exception.
3. Change the function to pass output by reference and return an error code.
4. Force the user to get the point with a strongly typed `enum class`.

**Option 1**

```
float Vec4::operator[](const unsigned int i) {
    switch (i)
    case 0: 
      return x;
    ...
    default:
        return nan;
```

**Option 2**

```
default:
    throw InvalidInputException;
```

**Option 3**

```
typedef ErrCode int;
const int ERROR = -1;
const int SUCCESS = 1;
...
ErrCode Vec4::getPoint(const unsigned int i, float &ouptut) {
    ...
    switch (i)
    case 0: 
      output = x;
      return SUCCESS;
    default:
      return ERROR;
```

**Option 4 (c++11)**

```
class Vec4 {
...
public:
    enum class VecMem {X, Y, Z, W};
    float Vec4::getPoint(VecMem member) {
        switch (member):
            case X:
                return x;
        ...
```

Usage:

```
Vec4.getPoint(Vec4::VecMem::X);
```

Comment: You could also set a global variable as an error indicator (or set a member variable), take a caller-supplied function pointer to call on error, `longjmp` out, `abort()` the whole process, or go into an infinite loop.

Comment: @melpomene, true and true, all seem a bit extreme for a function likely returning a point.

Comment: Ooh! We can be even more extreme: `system("shutdown -h now");`

Comment: @melpomene That would certainly "break" the function as requested by the OP.

Comment: The first one is most likely OK, assuming a float representation with NaNs.

Comment: IMO proposals 1, 3, and 4 don't solve the problem. I think that author would like to terminate the program on such an erroneus call (use offensive programming http://wiki.c2.com/?OffensiveProgramming)

Comment: @MaciejChałapuk Perhaps you should clarify this with the OP and create your answer. While i understand the idea behind OffensivePrograming. The OP would be making the first vector lib like this ever ...

Comment: Indeed I'll use an exception (first time doing this) I'd have liked it an other way but it seems I can't do better 
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @melpomene I say we nuke the entire site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Ben I wouldn't say implementing first library like this is much of a meritorical argument :) Besides, it's not true at all. I'd say there are plenty Java vector libs that use Offensive Programming https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/la4j/Vector.java

Comment: @MaciejChałapuk In rebuttal, 1. This is not java. Name a production vector library in `c++` that does offensive programming. 2. #4 is the ultimate solution, the user wont even be able to compile unless they use the correct input.

Comment: Ah sorry... True, #4 solves the problem. As for finding a library, I'll not actively look, but I promise to post it here after stumbling upon one. I think there are some since using `assert()` is an offensive programming technique.

Answer (score 0):

If your argument is known during the compilation, you can use a **static_assert**.

```
#include <cassert>;

constexpr float Vec4::operator[](const unsigned int i)
{
    static_assert(i <= 3);
    ...
}
```

Static assertions are not impacting performance as they are checked during the compilation.

If your argument isn't known during the compilation, you can use dynamic **assert**.

```
#include <cassert>;

float Vec4::operator[](const unsigned int i)
{
    assert(i <= 3);
    ...
}
```

Dynamic assertions are contained in compiler output only after setting compiler flags that enable them, so can be switched off easily.

Or you can just throw an **exception**.

```
float Vec4::operator[](const unsigned int i)
{
    if (i > 3)
    {
        throw BadArgumentException("i must be <= 3");
    }
    ...
}
```

Exceptions can contain a lot of information and be handled in other parts of the code, but have the biggest performance cost.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: I doubt a static_assert will be usable here, [it requires an expression determined at compile time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Converted_constant_expression)

Comment: I treated the code from the question as an example... Don't you think that it's a possible solution for the problem defined in thread's title?

Comment: Sure, but think about the case like `cin >> i; return someVector[i]`. This cannot be determined at compile time, hence your static assert cant work.

Comment: i is unsigned so will not be less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use "switch case " and for the case where value is différent bigger than 3 return a default state which can be a specific value reserved for this case

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using upcoming features, you can use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to do that:

```
std::optional<float> Vec4::operator[](const unsigned int i) {
    if(i == 0) return x;
    if(i == 1) return y;
    if(i == 2) return z;
    if(i == 3) return w;
    return {};
}
```

The drawback is that the caller must check the validity of the returned value (using either the `operator bool` or the `has_value` member function) or use the `value_or` member function to get a default value for *empty* optionals.